# Formal pgsql and PostgreSQL syntax for highlighting and checking

Tags: postgresql, syntax-highlighting, plpgsql

I want to implement a syntax highlighter and checker for postgresql DDL and DML including plpgsql. I do not need support for other languages.

Is there a formal definition in EBNF or similar I can build on?

Comment: There is a grammar file that might be of help: http://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=blob_plain;f=src/backend/parser/README;hb=master

Comment: What about [pgcli](http://pgcli.com/index) or [pgedit](http://pgedit.com/) ?